# How to get a class instance name or the right format for eval(class_instance."func1().func2()") in Python?

Tags: python, parameters, eval, instance

In the code below I can get the class name via:

```
s.__class__.__name__   #Seq
```

but I can not get the intance name "s" directly, this will be problem if i use eval() in:

```
eval(s."head(20).tail(10)")      # must be eval("s.head(20).tail(10)")
```

And

```
def foo(i_cls):
    eval(i_cls."head(20).tail(10)")
```

How?

Code

```
class Seq(object):
        def __init__(self, seq):
            self.seq = seq
            self.name = ""              **#EDIT**
        def __repr__(self):
            return repr(self.seq)
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.seq)
        def all(self):
            return Seq(self.seq[:])
        def head(self, count):
            return Seq(self.seq[:count])
        def tail(self, count):
            return Seq(self.seq[-count:])

s = Seq(range(0, 100))
print s.head(20).tail(10)             # "Method chain" invoking, work as linux command:
                                      #     seq 0 100 | head -20 | tail -10
```

**EDIT: in order to eval(), I defined the function below  that may work.**

```
def cls_name_eval(i_cls, eval_str, eval_name = "i_cls"):
    i_cls.name = eval_name
    eval_str = i_cls.name + "." + eval_str   #i_cls.head(20).tail(10)
    return i_cls, eval_str

i_cls, eval_str = cls_name_eval(s, "head(20).tail(10)")
eval(eval_str)
```

Or

```
def cls_name_eval(i_cls, eval_str, eval_name = "i_cls"):
    i_cls.name = eval_name
    eval_str = i_cls.name + "." + eval_str
    #print i_cls.head(20).tail(10)             #i_cls.head(20).tail(10), will not working, must print?
    return eval(eval_str)

print cls_name_eval(s, "head(20).tail(10)")

v = Seq(range(44, 200))
print cls_name_eval(v, "head(20).tail(10)")


*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
>>>
[9, 5, 1]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter all instances of class A and then evaluate `call func_foo for them` then you are also able to use Ignacio code with a small addition:

```
map(lambda inst: getattr(inst, 'func_foo')(), filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, A), locals().values()))
```

I am sorry if it is duplicate.

EDITED:

```
l = locals()
instanceNames = filter(lambda x: isinstance(l[x], Seq), l)# gives you all Seq instances names
map(lambda inst: eval(inst+'.head(20).tail(10)'), filter(lambda x: isinstance(l[x], Seq), l))
```

OR:

```
instName = 'tst'
exec('%s = Seq(%s)'% (instName, str(range(100))))
eval('%s.head(20).tail(10)' % variable)
```

Comment: @Artsiom, thanks for your code, but I think your code will been applied to all the Seq instances, but I only need one instance, say "s". any comment?

Comment: instanceNames contains names for all Seq instances so you can use any single as well as all. Probably i could not get what you actually need. Could you tell me what do you have so i will have ability to understand how to deal with such input.

Comment: @Artsiom, thanks, c my update: I defined a `Seq` class can accept method chain invoking,  one of the instances of the Seq class named s or some other name, there's external string "head(20).tail(10)" which is part of eval()-able string "s.head(20).tail(10)", now I only need the s's var name string "s" as the prefix to get the "s.head(20).tail(10)", it should be the hard part, then I try to define the function `cls_name_eval()` to avoid this problem.

Comment: Ok, but why you can't use instanceNames list?

Comment: that is because I have no idea which instance is what I need when I just need one, they may have a lot of Seq instances in the instanceNames list, right?

Comment: It depends on your scope. This list will have as many instances as you create. However you are able to add any identifier to you class and then to look for it through collection of all instances. Why do you need instance name - i mean that is not clear why you don't have this name if you have created it?

Comment: generally, it is for a one-off design testing console for one-off generating :-( I do not want to hardcode the instance name in code then the prefix of the eval() string is also can not be hardcoded.

Comment: Oh - seems he had removed his sample.